# Check if index exists for Array of NSURL

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsurl

I have an array of NSURL with 3 elements. I am modifying and reseting(making nil) the elements, so I need to check if the element with the index exists. Otherwise, I receive array out of index. My problem is that as this array is array of NSURLs, I can't use many functions.

`data[0][0]`, `data[0][1]`, `data[0][3]`

- So using `self.data[0][2].absoluteString` would crash.
- I can't use `indices.contains(index)` to check

What is the way of checking if the array element of `NSURL` with index path exists?

I want to do..

```
if (data[0][0] exists) {
    // do
}
```

Comment: if let = data[0][0] as? NSURL {
    // do
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it through `count`

```
var data = [[String]]()

let data1 = ["test 1","test 2"]
data.append(data1)

let indexToFind = 1

if data[0].count > indexToFind {
    print("found")
    print("value \(data[0][indexToFind])")
}
else {
    print("not found")
}
```

---

If indexToFind = 2 then you will get

> not found

If indexToFind = 1 then you will get

> found
>
> value test 2

---

**FOR URL**

You can count characters in url by **`absoluteString.characters.count`**

```
var data = [[NSURL?]]()

let data1 = [NSURL(string: ""),NSURL(string: ""),NSURL(string:"http://google.com")]
data.append(data1)

let indexToFind = 2

if data[0].count > indexToFind {
    print("found")
    print("value \(data[0][indexToFind]!)")

    if data[0][indexToFind]!.absoluteString.characters.count > 0 {
        print("this is an url")
    }
}
else {
    print("not found")
}
```

OUTPUT :

> found
>
> value http://google.com
>
> this is an url

Comment: The thing is, in viewDidLoad, I had to do `let emptyURL = NSURL(string: ""); urls.append(emptyURL!)`. That's why I should handle nil values individually. Because the array may look like : `[ , , "url"]`

Comment: but enter just url string in array why you are entering the whole NSURL!! @senty

Answer (score 1):

A good pattern is:

```
if array.count > indexYouWantToAccess {
    // for sure the array will contain the index
}
```

In your case, you should check in this way

```
if data[0].count > index {
    let url = data[0][index]
    if url == nil {
        // Do whatever
    } else {
        // Take the absolute string
    }
}
```

To handle the `nil` elements you can do

```
for element in data[0] {
    if element == nil {
        // Is nil
    } else {
        // Not nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Using your approach (2nd), I receive `Value of type [NSURL] has no member 'length'`

Comment: @senty I'm sorry, I was working with Javascript during the last week and I confused `count` (Swift) with `length` (Javascript). I updated the code

Comment: You should edit answer and replace `length` to `count`

Comment: Thanks. However, I got a bit confused. In my case, I may have 0 index empty, and then 3rd index full, and maybe 2nd index empty again. Wouldn't count just return the full count? I should handle for every single one rather than making it bulk imo

Comment: Using `Array` you cannot have those empty spaces. If you remove an object, the others will take the space left

Comment: I used `items.append(nil)`. The reason I am doing this is I have draggable cells, and I need to handle the nil value as a value actually.. That's why I need to check the nil state

Comment: But it won't notice if the previous element is empty or not.. I mean, if I have `[ , , url]`, index 0 and 1 will be nil whereas, 2 will be full. But the count would return 3. Instead, I want to know `if index 0 empty - do stuff`, `if index 1 empty - do stuff` kind of. I need to handle the nils.. But the nils are counted as elements too

Comment: So you should do it using a for loop. Anyway your question isn't clear as well, I still can't understand what you want to do. Check my post, I edited it.

Comment: Did you declare this array as array of Optionals?

Answer (score 0):

```
import Cocoa

var someInts:[Int] = [10, 20, 30]

for index in someInts {
 println( "Value of  index is \(index)")
}


import Cocoa

var someInts:[Int] = [10, 20, 30]

for var index = 0; index < someInts.length; ++index {
   println( "Value of someInts[\(index)] is \(someInts[index])")
}
```

It has all the info : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swift/swift_for_loop.htm

Comment: How can I return both value and index of the value? Would using a for loop a good way of achieving this? If I use `urls in data[0]`, it would just return the value and not the index, no?

Comment: In that case you can use the generic for loop. import Cocoa

    var someInts:[Int] = [10, 20, 30]

    for var index = 0; index < 3; ++index {
      println( "Value of someInts[\(index)] is \(someInts[index])")
    }

Comment: Can you please give an example in the answer part?

Comment: Rather than `[10, 20, 30]`, think it as `[20, nil, 30]` but for NSURL. I think this won't work in my case :/

Comment: Dude, I know how for loop works. The reason it won't work, because in the NSURL array (data), I have the array like `[ , , "url"]`, so I should handle each one separately

Comment: @senty When in the for loop you are sure that the index exists , now you can check for the data at that index . example data[0][i] cast it as string and check for its length or number of characters.

Answer (score -1):

```
let array = [1, 2, 3]

for index in -20...20 {
    if let item = array[safe: index] {
        print(item)
    }
}
```